# Specify IP address of service in WCF client configuration where service certificate is used

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a WCF self-hosted service that is accessed over a VPN by client applications. This works in most cases, but some clients are unable to find the server by the DNS name. I want to configure it so that the IP address is specified as well. I cannot simply use the server's IP address instead of the server name in the client config because then it fails the security check because the remote endpoint provides a DNS claim of its server name. I could replace the server certificate with one specifiying the IP address as the subject name, but my understanding is that this would not work either.

How can I change the configuration so that the client can find the service by its Ip address while still using the server name for its identity?

Service configuration:

```
...
   <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="gzipBinding">
                <gzipMessageEncoding />
                <sslStreamSecurity />
                <tcpTransport>
                </tcpTransport>
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ClientCertAuthenticationBinding">
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
        <service name="MyServices.HandshakeService" behaviorConfiguration="HandshakeServiceBehavior">
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://10.0.0.4:8000/Handshake"/>
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ClientCertAuthenticationBinding" contract="OCS.Client.KnownLayer.IHandshaker"/>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>

    <!--For debugging purposes set the includeExceptionDetailInFaults attribute to true-->
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="HandshakeServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
                <serviceCredentials>
                    <serviceCertificate findValue="MyServiceComputerName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
                    <clientCertificate>

                        <!-- <authentication certificateValidationMode="Custom" customCertificateValidatorType="Rdt.CertificateIdentification.ClientAuthentication.MyX509CertificateValidator, OCS"/>-->
                        <!-- The custom validator replicates the chaintrust functionality and extends it with a check against the identity database-->
                        <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
                    </clientCertificate>
                </serviceCredentials>

            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Client configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>

    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://MyServiceComputerName:8000/Handshake" binding="wsHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="ClientCertificateBehavior"
      bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IHandshaker" contract="IHandshaker"
      name="WSHttpBinding_IHandshaker"/>
    </client>

    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IHandshaker">
                <security>
                    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ClientCertificateBehavior">
                <clientCredentials>
                    <clientCertificate findValue="MyClientCert" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
                    <serviceCertificate>
                        <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
                    </serviceCertificate>
                </clientCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

> but some clients are unable to find the server by the DNS name

You can resolve this issue by reviewing the **[Troubleshooting Domain Name System (DNS) issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/dns/troubleshoot/troubleshoot-dns-data-collection)** document.

You can try the following methods, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6911265/17218587) for details

1.) Add the IP to the endpoint address & add a host name with the base IP address like so:

```
<endpoint
  address="http://xx.xx.xx.xx/ServiceApp/Service.svc"
  binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IService">
</endpoint>
<host>
  <baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="http://xx.xx.xx.xx/ServiceApp/" />
  </baseAddresses>
</host>
```

2.) If you have a domain name ([www.myDomain.com](http://www.myDomain.com)) then add this to the host header in IIS.
3.) Add the IP address & computer name to the clients hosts file (easy fix not always possible to get all of your clients to add this to their host file however)